# String formatting in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have added a column to a table that will store a formatted string based on concatenating a number of other columns so I can search over it more easily.
In order to save loading the whole table into another app and updating the new column then persisting, I want to write an UPDATE SQL query. But I can't figure out how to take an integer column and format it as in this example

Source column value = 1
Destination column value = 0001

I want the 3 leading zeros to be added in SQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Right( '0000' + cast( 1 as varchar),4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to prepend seroes:

```
right('0000' + cast(MyColumn, nvarchar(4), 4)
```

This will concatenate `0000` with whatever value there is in `MyColumn` and return four rightmost characters.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Source),4) AS ColWithZeros
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is coming from an integer column, I would remove the dependency on the string "0001".

Also, most of the other answers assume that 1 is the only data, I would suggest you need to find the number of digits, then add the appropriate number of zeroes. As it will fail with any aother data (10,20, 100 etc).

Comment: I believe that by taking the right-most 4 characters, the proposed solutions will handle any number of digits in the input.